# SUBSTRING CON FINDSTRING COLUMNA DERIVADA

Tags: ssis

Necesito obtener el valor que se encuentra despues de 'Accion="' y antes de '" Desde', la idea es obtener lo que se encuentra entre las comillas, lo mismo lo debo hacer con los demás valores, Hasta, IdViaje y Viaje Linea.

La cadena es la siguiente:

**'<VacioLimitacion Accion="Desvio" Desde="PA54905" Hasta="PA55013" IdViaje="3" ViajeLinea="2" '**

He tratado de hacerlo, pero no me resulta, estoy usando una **columna derivada en ssis**, usando las funciones FINDSTRING y SUBSTRING.

Por el momento, estoy probando el sql con una función que es similar a FINDSTRING, esto es lo que tengo:

**SUBSTRING(DE_PARAMETROS,CHARINDEX('Accion="',de_parametros,8)+8,CHARINDEX('" D',DE_PARAMETROS,1)-2)**

Si alguien me pudiese ayudar se lo agradecería, por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disculpas de antemano por el traductor de google.

Resuelva este problema agregando 3 columnas derivadas en su tarea de flujo de datos.

### DER EncontroPosición

El primero encontrará la posición de la cadena `Accion="` Agregar una nueva columna llamada `posicionDeAccion`

```
FINDSTRING(de_parametros,"Accion=\"",1) + LEN("Accion=\"")
```

Agrego la longitud de la cadena que estamos buscando a la posición que genera FINDSTRING para mover el valor a la posición correcta.

### DER ProximaCita

Usaremos esa posición para encontrar el primer `"` de cierre. Usaremos la nueva columna, posicionDeAccion, para gregue una segunda columna nueva llamada `posicionDeCita`

```
FINDSTRING([de_parametros], "Accion=\"", [posicionDeAccion])
```

### DER EncontroAccion

Ahora que conocemos la posición inicial y la posición final, esto se convierte en una simple operación SUBSTRING.

```
SUBSTRING([de_parametros], [posicionDeAccion], [posicionDeCita])
```

### ¿Por qué este enfoque?

Dividir expresiones grandes en otras más pequeñas le permite solucionar problemas. Por ejemplo, si los parámetros no tenían un valor de Acción, la subcadena devolverá un valor "raro". Al inspeccionar los dos valores que calculamos junto con los datos de origen, sería obvio que debemos protegernos contra esa condición. O si hubiera un NULL. Para manejar esos casos, siga agregando columnas derivadas que se construyen entre sí para llegar a la solución final.

enfoque inglés para una similar

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67925957/use-ssis-expresion-to-break-up-full-name-in-to-seperate-fields-last-first-middl/67927002#67927002

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda